# Diameter of $\gamma(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x+y|}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $\gamma(x,y)=\dfrac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$.

Proof that $\gamma(x,y)$ is indeed a metric in $\mathbb{R}$, and show that $Diam_{\gamma}(\mathbb{R})=1$.

Showing that's is a metric is eazy using the auxiliary function $f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$, but I don't know where to start to demonstrate the diameter.

Any leads?

Comment: Take the sup for $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gamma(n,0) = \frac{n}{n+1} \to 1$ while $\gamma(x,y) < 1$ for all $x,y$.

So $1$ is an upperbound for $\{\gamma(x,y)\mid x,y \in \Bbb R\}$ and the limit implies there can be no smaller one. So the diameter (i.e. the *supremum*, least upper bound,  of that set) equals $1$..

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

You have $$|x|<1+|x|,$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$.